# CSS/HTML Escrevendo ao redor de uma imagem

Tags: html, css, imagem

Bom dia, possuo uma imagem "quadrada" mas em formato de pentagono, preciso escrever nas bordas dela:

Imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso escrever em formato de pentagono também, como no exemplo:

[image: Final]

Outro requisito é que, provavelmente o texto será alterado, mas ele deve crescer para fora da imagem, ou seja, nunca sobrepor ela..

Alguém indica algum plugin que facilite, ou mesmo no CSS puro, os exemplos que eu acho são somente para texto externo, mas completo e não com frases.

à quem poder ajuda, agradeço!

Comment: Só posicionar com **CSS** amigo.

Comment: @LeAndrade mas a imagem central tem que ficar com que tipo de position?

Comment: @LeAndradesou péssimo com CSS, as spans com o texto ficam com position relative?

Comment: É responsivo o site?

Comment: @LeAndrade não, o site não é responsivo, é um sistema interno!

Comment: Coloca os textos e a imagem num container (div por exemplo) e posiciona eles com `margin` e `position: absolute`, veja esse exemplo se ajuda: http://jsfiddle.net/zhrpxy0t/6/  
Se quiser posto uma resposta com em exemplo 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um modelo. Repare que os texto a direita são alinhado a esquerda, e os textos da esquerda são alinhado a direita, assim eles crescem para fora da imagem. O Texto do centro vai sempre ficar centralizado, mas como sua imagem está cortada errada ele fica um pouco desalinhado.

O Pai no caso deve ter `position:relative` e os filhos `absolute` e a imagem usei como `background` para deixar o código mais limpo apenas.

Veja o resultado.

```css
  html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 240px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4449Y.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.wrap > span {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.wrap > span:nth-child(1) {
  color: darkred;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 60px;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 50%;
} 
.wrap > span:nth-child(2) {
  color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 80px;
  top: 8rem;
  left: 50%;
}
.wrap > span:nth-child(3){
  color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.wrap > span:nth-child(4){
  color: orangered;
  margin-right: 120px;
  top: 8rem;
  right: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}

.wrap > span:nth-child(5) {
  color: tomato;
  margin-right: 100px;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrap">
    <span>item 1</span>
    <span>item 2</span>
    <span>item 3</span>
    <span>item 4</span>
    <span>item 5</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo código Hugo, ficou perfeito para o que eu precisava.
Grato!

Comment: Tranquilo jovem sucesso ai. Só lembre-se de não deixar bordas brancas na imagem do fundo, pois se tiver por exemplo uma borda branca de um lado e não tiver do outro a imagem pode ficar desalinhada na tela.

Answer (score 0):

Cara o exemplo do Hugo já te atende, fiz um exemplo mais simples, como vc disse que não entende de **CSS**, ficar só com um exemplo com seletores mais avançados como no exemplo dele, acho que pode te confundir um pouco.

```css
#conteudo {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  top: 10%;
}
#texto1{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5%;
  left: 22%;
  color: red;
}
#texto2{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5%;
  right: 11%;
  color: #C0392B;
}
#texto3{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 19%;
  left: 7%;
  color: #DC7633;
}
#texto4{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 19%;
  right: 19%;
  color: #F4D03F;
}
#texto5{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 31%;
  left: 47%;
  color: #F5B041;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4449Y.png">
  <span id="texto1">Prevenção Social</span>
  <span id="texto2">Policiamento e Justiça</span>
  <span id="texto3">Fiscalização administrativa</span>
  <span id="texto4">Urbanismo</span>
  <span id="texto5">Tecnologia</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Faça o alinhamento tb jovem, se o seu texto da esquerda crescer ele está indo pra cima da imagem... Outra coisa que notei é que em tela Cheia os textos ficam muito distantes da imagem, acho que é pq vc usou valores em %

Comment: Sim Hugo, deixei assim exatamente para ele perceber, a questão do **left** e **right**, para ele mexer conforme precisar, ele disse que é **péssimo em css**, seria interessante ele mexer, tbm não vou dar o peixe de badeja para ele, tem que aprender a pescar, até pq vc já entregou a resposta para ele.

Comment: Ta certo, só aprende quem põem a mão na massa mesmo. Só comentei pq as vezes a gente posta as resposta e só depois se liga em algum detalhe.

Comment: De boas man, é nois Hugo.

Comment: Valeu pessoal! Muito obrigado pela contribuição dos senhores!